# Can't call function on react-native-video item

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm attempting to display an image and call a Video component onPress. The image displays fine, but I cannot get the video to play the same way I can get an alert to show.

Two images are displayed, if one is clicked then an alert shows. This works fine. If the other image is clicked, then the video should play.

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Image,
  Text,
  Component,
  AlertIOS,
  View,
} = React;

var Video = require('react-native-video');

class Mogul extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.playBroadchurch}>
          <Image
            style={{ height:150, width: 150 }}
            source={{uri: 'http://www.covermesongs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/NotoriousBIG.jpg'}}
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.showAlert}>
          <Image
            style={{ height:150, width: 150 }}
            source={{uri: 'http://www.covermesongs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/NotoriousBIG.jpg'}}
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }

  playBroadchurch() {
    return (
      <Video source={{uri: "broadchurch"}} // Can be a URL or a local file. 
       rate={1}                   // 0 is paused, 1 is normal. 
       volume={1}                 // 0 is muted, 1 is normal. 
       muted={false}                // Mutes the audio entirely. 
                    // Pauses playback entirely. 
       resizeMode={'contain'}           // Fill the whole screen at aspect ratio. 
       repeat={false}                // Repeat forever. 
       onLoad={this.setDuration}    // Callback when video loads 
       onProgress={this.setTime}    // Callback every ~250ms with currentTime 
       onEnd={this.onEnd}           // Callback when playback finishes 
       style={styles.video} />
    );
  }

  showAlert() {
    AlertIOS.alert('Notorious BIG', 'It was all a DREAM',
      [
        {text: 'Yep', onPress: () => console.log('Yep Pressed!')},
        {text: 'Nope', onPress: () => console.log('Nope Pressed!')},
      ]
    )
  }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return a component from an event handler, React Native doesn't do anything with it. Instead, you should set state on the component, and use that to decide whether to display the video or not. Something like this:

```js
var React = require('react-native');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Image,
  Text,
  Component,
  AlertIOS,
  View,
} = React;

var Video = require('react-native-video');

class Mogul extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.playBroadchurch = this.playBroadchurch.bind(this)
    this.state = {showBroadchurch: false};
  }

  render() {
    var videoDisplay;
    if (this.state.showBroadchurch) { // Switch between showing video and placeholder image
      videoDisplay = <Video source={{uri: "broadchurch"}} // Can be a URL or a local file. 
           rate={1}                   // 0 is paused, 1 is normal. 
           volume={1}                 // 0 is muted, 1 is normal. 
           muted={false}                // Mutes the audio entirely. 
                        // Pauses playback entirely. 
           resizeMode={'contain'}           // Fill the whole screen at aspect ratio. 
           repeat={false}                // Repeat forever. 
           onLoad={this.setDuration}    // Callback when video loads 
           onProgress={this.setTime}    // Callback every ~250ms with currentTime 
           onEnd={this.onEnd}           // Callback when playback finishes 
           style={styles.video} />;
    } else {
      videoDisplay = <Image
        style={{ height:150, width: 150 }}
        source={{uri: 'http://www.covermesongs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/NotoriousBIG.jpg'}}
      />;
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.playBroadchurch}>
          {videoDisplay}
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.showAlert}>
          <Image
            style={{ height:150, width: 150 }}
            source={{uri: 'http://www.covermesongs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/NotoriousBIG.jpg'}}
            />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );

  }

  playBroadchurch() {
    this.setState({showBroadchurch: true}); // Update state to show video
  }

  showAlert() {
    AlertIOS.alert('Notorious BIG', 'It was all a DREAM',
      [
        {text: 'Yep', onPress: () => console.log('Yep Pressed!')},
        {text: 'Nope', onPress: () => console.log('Nope Pressed!')},
      ]
    )
  }
};
```

Comment: that makes more sense, thank you. However, I'm getting "null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.showBroadchurch') when run in the iOS simulator. You're setting showBroadchurch to false in 'getInitialState' so i'm not understanding where it thinks it's getting null.

Comment: Oh, that's because this is an ES6 class instead of a `React.createComponent` call. With ES6 classes you just define the state in the constructor. I updated my code, so it should work now.

Comment: Now i'm receiving "Invariant Violation: onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child." Google doesn't seem to provide much insight. Apologies for the lack of knowledge, I'm trying to make sense of all this.

Comment: I also ran into that for the first time while I was testing my answer (though my solution shouldn't have that problem). The TouchableHighlight component is supposed to have exactly one child. From what I can tell, you get that error if it has zero or more than one children.

Comment: You say you ran into that error while testing, but it went away?

Comment: I accidentally removed one of the TouchableHighlight components' children. When I put it back, the error went away.

Comment: OK, I went ahead and copied and pasted your entire code to replace what I had and it works. There must have been a small change in your code I didn't notice between the fix. All works fantastic now, thanks!